# System icons disabled due to group policy

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

I'm unable to change some of my system tray icons for some reason. It tells me the following:

[image: image description here]

I'm the only user on this computer and it is not a member of any domain. And it has never been a member of any domain. This is very frustrating due to the fact that I use a VPN to connect to the terminal server at my work. I'm unable to do that now due to the fact that I do not have the option to enable my network tray icon.

Comment: It's not necessarily from a domain policy though. More likely local policy or registry change. Run `gpedit.msc` and check under the secion User configuration\Administrative templates\Start menu and task bar.

Comment: I checked all the group/user policies on my local machine using gpedit.msc and there were none set.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly likely that the user you are logged in as is not setup as an admin user on that installation of Windows.  There is probably another user account setup on the system that has admin rights.  Try to log in as that user.

Comment: I'm the only user. The default admin user has been disabled so I'm the only user. (checked it using "net user")

Comment: It looks like you have 3 account on the machine, Administrator, bas, guest.  I think you need to log in as the Administrator account to change those settings.

Comment: The administrator account is default. I disabled that account due to security reasons.

Comment: Can you verify that the account is actually an admin(screenshot maybe of the groups that account is in).

Comment: Here you go http://i.imgur.com/sZ3xU.png and here http://i.imgur.com/MyVxm.png